# Loading executable object files and creating private area

Tags: linux-kernel, process, memory, virtual-memory

I was reading a textbook on virtual memory and it says:

Any Linux program can invoke the loader by calling the `execve` function which does:

1. Delete the existing area structs in the user portion of the current process’s virtual address.
2. Create new area structs for the code, data, bss, and stack
   areas of the new program. All of these new areas are **private copy-on-write**. The code and data areas are mapped to the .text and .data sections of the a.out file
   [image]

I'm just thinking what if the program is a single process program(doesn't use `fork()`), when this single process starting at a virual address within let's say `.data` section of `a.out`, it will trigger a protection fault, and then the fault handler notices that the protection exception was caused by the process trying to write to a page in a private copy-on-write area, it creates a new copy of the page in physical memory.

I see two problems here:

1. Even though there is not a second process that can share the same page in physical memory, the private area's copy-on-write mechanism still create a new page, which is not useful at all since there is only one process, no other process will write to this page, every time the process wants to modify a page will trigger an exception to be handled, which is quite inefficient?
2. A new copy of the page in physical memory is created, what about the original page which is not referenced by the process anymore? if the old page resides in physical memory, isn't it a waste of memory?

Comment: Multi-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63989087/340790 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing one key piece of information: when the kernel handles a page fault corresponding to a copy-on-write scenario, if the target page is used by a single process, it makes the page writable instead of copying it.

The kernel keeps a counter for each page, [`mapcount` in `struct page`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.10/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L183); that counter is 0 if a single process maps the page, and is incremented every time a new process maps it, and decremented when it’s unmapped (*e.g.* because it’s copy-on-write and a process tried to write to it).

Comment: thank you for your answer. another question is, how does kernel know a targer page is used by a single process or multiple processes?

Comment: See the update.